# How can I add event handling in each row in ListView

Tags: android

I create a CursorAdapter to provide data for my ListView.

I implement the bindView() method to show data in a row of my Listview.
But at the end of my bindView, I add an clickListener to it.  But when I run it on emulator, I don't see any print statement.

Can you please tell me how to add event handling in a row in ListView?

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println (" getting an onclick event....");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach OnItemClickListener to the ListView - not the rows individually.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Clicked");
    }
});
```